# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

> Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Item__order__3AE27131". The conflict occurred in database "pmall", table "dbo.ItemSaved", column 'id'.

Here's my table:

#### ItemSavedUnits

- id
- ItemID (is set in this table a FK to Item.id)
- ...etc.

Here's my insert statement:

```
insert into ItemSavedUnits (ItemID, name, Price)
select ItemID, name,Price
from ItemUnits where ItemID = 92439
```

I don't really understand why if I a FK constraint on ItemSavedUnits.ItemID that is related to Item.ItemID and ItemUnits has no constraints at all why I'm getting a problem inserting into ItemSavedUnits. The ItemID I'm tryign to insert does exist in the Item table.

Comment: Can you post your table structure for ItemUnits?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure that ItemId 92439 exists in the Item table, and not just in ItemUnits?

or

Is your select statement returning null?

Comment: I am 110% sure it exists.  I justqueried it on that table.

Comment: If the select would return null, I think it would simply insert nothing. So I will go with Jim B on this one, most likely the constraint is not respected because the item id doesn't exist in the table ItemSaved. Maybe the constraint isn't link the to the right table/column.

Comment: No, the select statement returns a valid record

Comment: ItemId is in the table ItemSaved I'm looking right at it and it's a FK to Item.Id

Comment: Ah!  correct.  the stupid column was named ItemID however the FK specified is actually pointing to a different Primary table than Item.  Thanks!

Comment: Once again, poor naming by my damn boss.  Name it what it is, don't take shortcuts.  Damn it.

Comment: Hence the importance of having an updated (and well done) data model. I am suffering too the consequences of not having it in the project currently assigned to me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a row in ItemUnits with that ID first - what does the SELECT statement part of your insert return? No rows?

Also, is there a trigger on the ItemSavedUnits table that could be causing problems?

Answer (score 1):

Your foreign key constraint violation doesn't appear to deal with the `ItemSavedUnits` table - the violation exception is being thrown by the constraint on the `ItemSaved` table, not the `ItemSavedUnits` table.  Is there a trigger on `ItemSavedUnits` that's trying to insert into `ItemSaved`?