# SqlException The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint `FK_Kupovina_Kupac`. The conflict occurred in database `OnlineApoteka`, table `dbo.Kupac`, column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.

I'm really confused I do not know why we do not allow? I reported a bug, in throw ex; ?

```
public static void Kupi(long lekID, int kolicina, double cena, long nacinIsporukeID, string korisnickoIme)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    try
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OnlineApotekaConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();

        string updateLager = @"
        UPDATE  Lager
        SET Kolicina=Kolicina-@Kolicina
        WHERE LekID=@LekID";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateLager, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LekID", lekID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kolicina", kolicina);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string insertIntoKupovina=@"
            INSERT INTO Kupovina (KupacID, LekID, Datum, Kolicina, Cena, NacinIsporukeID) 
            VALUES (@KupacID, @LekID, @Datum, @Kolicina, @Cena, @NacinIsporukeID)";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(insertIntoKupovina, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KupacID", KupacAdapter.GetID(korisnickoIme));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LekID", lekID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", DateTime.Now.Date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kolicina", kolicina);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cena", cena);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NacinIsporukeID", nacinIsporukeID);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I have a routine event for the button Buy.
When you click Kupi, should be removed from the table Lager volumes and placed in the Kupac Kupovina

```
protected void kupiButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    KupovinaAdapter.Kupi(Convert.ToInt64(kupovinaGreedView.SelectedDataKey["LekID"].ToString()),
        Convert.ToInt32(kolicinaTextBox.Text),
        Convert.ToInt64(kupovinaGreedView.SelectedDataKey["Cena"].ToString()),
        Convert.ToInt64(nacinIsporukeDropDownList.SelectedValue),
        User.Identity.Name);
}

protected void kupovinaGreedView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(kupovinaGreedView.SelectedDataKey["Lek"].ToString()))
    {
        LekLabel.Text = kupovinaGreedView.SelectedDataKey["Lek"].ToString();
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(kupovinaGreedView.SelectedDataKey["Kolicina"].ToString()))
    {
        kolicinaValidator.MaximumValue = kupovinaGreedView.SelectedDataKey["Kolicina"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Clarify your question please. What does ' I do not know why we do not allow? I reported a bug, in throw ex; ?' mean?   Also, read up on what 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint' means, and see if it perhaps could explain the problem with your code.

Comment: I *think* the OP wants to know why the Exception is still being raised as opposed to just ignoring...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828376/the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the error is because of how the database schema is defined. In particular the table `Kupac` is used in a relation with the table `Kupovina` such that the `KupacID` in `Kupovina` must match a value from the `ID` field in the `Kupac` table.

Because of this you cannot insert records into the `Kupovina` table using a `KupacID` that doesn't already exist in the `Kupac` table - it's a Foreign-Key Constraint violation.

You have two options:

1. make sure you first insert a record into the Kupac table
2. drop the foreign-key constraint from the database schema if that makes business-sense

But you should examine the output of the `KupacAdapter.GetID(korisnickoIme)` which is what is supposed to provide the `KupacID` value. If this method for some reason does not return a valid ID (one from the `Kupovina` table) than the insert will fail as explained above.

In case you are wondering why the Exception is not begin *"handled"* than that is because of the code in your catch block. You are basically taking the exception and re-throwing it which is sort of pointless. You might as well just not have a catch block at all..

```
try {
   // ...
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    throw ex;    //  <--- this just re-throws the same exception that was caught!
}
finally { 

}
```

Is, for the most part, nearly equivalent to:

```
try {
   // ...
}    
finally { 

}
```

The difference is only in how much of the stack trace is preserved along with the exception, but the exception is bubbled up nonetheless.

Comment: These are rows of tables Kupac and Kupovina: Table Kupac ID JMBG Ime Prezime Adresa KorisnickoIme Telefon Email table Kupac FK_Kupovina_Kupac and table Kupovina ID KupacID LekID Datum Kolicina Cena NacinIsporukeID

Comment: And what is your question exactly? Did my answer help you?

Comment: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Kupovina_Kupac". The conflict occurred in database "OnlineApoteka", table "dbo.Kupac", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.I checked all the answers from the forum right question is how to solve the problem when I connected all do not know where I'm wrong?

Comment: Please read my answer again. Also, please understand that the context is very limiting if your names are in Croatian?! - so it's hard for us to determine what is it that your code is actually supposed to represent. But more importantly the error you are getting is the result of conflicts at the database level. You are trying to insert a record into Kupovina that is supposed to be relatd to a record from Kupac which **DOES NOT EXIST** int Kupac. Most likely this has to do with the result of **KupacAdapter.GetID(korisnickoIme)**

Comment: Actually, there is a difference between the Questioner's code and your empty try catch:  http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2007/08/20/Difference-between-quotthrowquot-and-quotthrow-exquot-in-.NET.aspx

Comment: @Poldie - you're right, I've updated the answer to reflect the subtle difference.

Answer (score 0):

The `Kupac` table does not have the `KupacID` value in that table that you are trying to insert into the `Kupovina` table

The `KupacID` column in the `Kupac` table is the primary key, while the `KupacID` column in the `Kupovina` table is the foreign key pointing back to the primary key

Read up on [Foreign Keys](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/foreign-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are catching the key violation with `catch (Exception ex)` - however you then rethrow the Exception there.

Do you have an error handler in the calling routine?

`throw ex` - does not "handle" an error - it is simply raising another (although, the same one in this case - the one that has been caught)

If you are expecting this *specific error* then you should catch this specific error by `catch (SqlException ex)` - and then check for this particular error. If it is *not* this error then `throw ex;` back up the call-stack... If it *is* this error then you can ignore (but it would be better to just avoid this kind of INSERT in the first place...)

Comment: I have no head for routine errors.When you click the Kupi button on the form needs to happen purchases.I have a routine event for the button Kupi