# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint. The conflict occurred in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have been having this problem for a couple of hours now. In `SQL Server`, I ran this query :

```
INSERT INTO USERS_AVATAR(userId, avatId) VALUES ('1', '213');
INSERT INTO USERS_AVATAR(userId, avatId) VALUES ('2', '312');
```

but the message shows up saying :

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKUSERS_AVAT731248". The conflict occurred in database "gk314", table "gk314.USERS", column 'userId'.
>
> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKUSERS_AVAT731248". The conflict occurred in database "gk314", table "gk314.USERS", column 'userId'.

Help please!

Comment: Unrelated but: don't use string literals for numbers `'1'` is a string. `1` is a number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828376/the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 11):

Before inserting userIds `1` and `2` into `USERS_AVATAR`, you must first insert them into table `USERS`.  That is what the FOREIGN KEY constraint is requiring.

Comment: this is my query to create the gk314.users table: "INSERT INTO USERS(userId, email, password, status) VALUES ('gk314', 'gk314@hotmail.com',' gk314', 'strong');"

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key constraints are SQL's way of saying "this table expects data to exist in other tables". It allows you to reference other tables without the data having to exist twice or to be kept in sync.

In this case, there's a table for user data (`USERS`) and a table for avatar data (`AVATARS`), and the `USERS_AVATAR` table links the two together. You will need to add a user to the users table, then an avatar to the avatar table, then you can link the two together. It will look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO USERS (userId, email, password, status) VALUES (1, 'gk314@hotmail.com',' gk314', 'strong')
INSERT INTO AVATARS (avatId, name, ...) VALUES (1, 'Avatar1', ...)
INSERT INTO USERS_AVATAR (userId, avatId) VALUES (1, 1)
```

---

Original Answer:

This means that there's a table, `gk314.USERS`, that doesn't have a `userId` that matches the `userId` you're attempting to add to `USERS_AVATAR`. Check the `USERS` table and add users with `userId` 1 and 2, and then you should be able to add to the `USERS_AVATAR` table.

Comment: this is my query to create the gk314.users table: "INSERT INTO USERS(userId, email, password, status) VALUES ('gk314', 'gk314@hotmail.com',' gk314', 'strong');"

Comment: i TRIED IT BUT IT SAYS "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'gk314' to data type int."

Comment: Then you can't use `gk314` as the `userId`. Change your `INSERT INTO USERS` to `... VALUES(1, 'gk314@hotmail.com, ...)`

Comment: i did as u said but it says" Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKUSERS_AVAT239440". The conflict occurred in database "gk314", table "gk314.AVATARS", column 'avatId'.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: Sounds like it's the same issue, just for the `AVATARS` table. Make sure you've added an avatar to that table with the appropriate ID before you attempt to write to the `USERS_AVATAR` table.

Comment: add an avatar to the users table?

Comment: Add an avatar to the `AVATARS` table.

Comment: MY avatar table has " avatid, name, ..."

Comment: MY AVATAR TABLE HAS GOT "avatid" but i still cant figure out the problem. thanks for the help so far..