# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables , one to one relationship i makes DetailsID of projectDetails FK in ID of projects table:

```
 projects: 
         ID,         //has FK With DetailsID in Details table & auto identity (1,1)
         ProjectName,
         Areas,
         PaymentSystem,
         ReceivedDate,
         PropertyClassification,
         ProjectImage

  ProjectDetails:
     DetailsID ,auto identity ( 1,1)
     ProjectDetailName,
     ProjectDetailImage
```

I am trying to insert new record in projects table , gives me this error at this line of code  :

```
    con.Open();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); // when execute
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Projects_ProjectDetails". The conflict occurred in database "AlamaarRealEstate", table "dbo.ProjectDetails", column 'DetailsID'.

and this is my stored to insert :

```
ALTER proc [Insert_Project]
   @Projectname                    NVARCHAR(MAX) , 
   @areas                          NVARCHAR(MAX) , 
   @Paymentsystem                  NVARCHAR(MAX) , 
   @Receiveddate                   date , 
   @Classification                 NVARCHAR(MAX) , 
   @Projectimage                   Nvarchar(MAX) 
  as

  INSERT INTO dbo.Projects
      (            
        ProjectName,
        Areas,
        PaymentSystem,
        ReceivedDate,
        PropertyClassification,
        ProjectImage                                                     
      ) 
 VALUES 
      ( 
        @Projectname ,
        @areas,
        @Paymentsystem ,
        @Receiveddate ,
        @Classification,
        @Projectimage          

      )
```

Comment: Please share full details of both tables.

Comment: Are you able to script out the DDL of your tables?  It seems likely that your foreign key is backwards (or wrong in some other way).  The way your error message reads, the ProjectDetails is being treated as the parent table.  Furthermore, in your text you say the Project table has a FK... but it should be the Project Details table that has a FK referencing the parent.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I updated the quotation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828376/the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 6):

The question explains the answer. `Referential Integrity` is not maintained properly, you are trying to insert into a child table for which the master value does not exist. Please insert values to `Project_details` first. This will resolve your issue. If you did not what this to throw an error, just check the existence of the `DetailID` in `Projects` table before inserting.

Comment: Ah.. why this was down voted? Please explain. This has become a pain. People are acting oversmart?

Comment: Question suggests that `Projects` is master table. Tables are wrongly defined.

Comment: Where it mentioned Projects as the master table? He mentioned like ID has a foreign key with ProjectDetails. Also from the error, it is clearly known which is the master table. Its really paining.

Comment: Exactly. The details of the table definitions are needed. Secondly, the insert statement has not included ID. We dont know if ID is defined as `Identity` type column.

Comment: Did you down vote my post? If so why did you down vote the answer based on your assumptions? Identity type? Please look at the error and find out the model from that.

Comment: I down voted because lack of details. The detailed table definition is needed before it can be answer precisely. The OP didnt include ID in insert. Even though ProjectDetails table contains expected values still insert will fail since it doesn't attempt to add value to ID column.

Comment: In such cases, please down vote the question. If you feel something is not correct in my post, then I will agree.

Answer (score 2):

Without more detail your question is hard to answer.  For instance in your procedure you do explicit column naming for inserts and LEAVE OUT the column you are having a problem with.  So if the proc was wrong it would be bombing with your example foreign key constraint error.  But you are not even listing the 'ID' field to insert into with the procedure.  So this is common if you are using an 'Identity' field to self seed, but you are claiming it is a foreign key.  So like others have commented, without more code to show the exact way your tables are made it's hard to guess.  Here is a self extracting example you could run that shows if a column is nullable and I had a key constraint it would work.  Without the exact code of the tables as well as the proc it is hard to tell.  What you gave is pseudo code.

```
USE Tester  --just a test database I have, you can use whatever database you want
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('Projects') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE Projects

IF OBJECT_ID('ProjectDetails') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE ProjectDetails

create TABLE ProjectDetails
(
    DetailsID INT CONSTRAINT PK_DetailsId PRIMARY KEY,
    ProjectDetailName VARCHAR(32)
  )

CREATE TABLE Projects 
(
    Id INT CONSTRAINT FK_Projects_ProjectDetails FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES ProjectDetails(DetailsId),         
    ProjectName varchar(32)

)
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('Insert_Project') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROC Insert_Project
GO

Create proc Insert_Project
   @Projectname                    NVARCHAR(MAX) 
  as

  INSERT INTO dbo.Projects  ( ProjectName ) 
  VALUES (  @Projectname )
GO

Select *
From dbo.Projects

EXEC dbo.Insert_Project @Projectname = N'Test' -- nvarchar(max)

Select *
From dbo.Projects
```

Comment: Thanks I agree with your assessment by the way.  I just wanted to lay it all out to show that there is a lot missing from the equation to properly know where the fault is at.  Generally like you already said it is self evident constraint problem that is fixed by defining that.  But if it is a nullable(in my example) type it won't matter.  Without knowing more from the question it is hard to tell.

Comment: i have ID in projects  table identity (1,1) and DetailsID in ProjectDetails identity (1,1)

Comment: You should not attempt a seeding of the same column you have a foreign key to.  Create a new column that has the foreign key reference if you want a one to one relationship.  And generally best practice is naming it the same name of the column you are relating to.